# Save webpage using Ctrl + S

Tags: python, html, selenium, save

I'm trying to save a complete webpage using Ctrl + S on Chrome. I need save completely, every html files, like using Ctrl + S.

I'm trying this two forms on "save", but doesn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'https://www.google.com'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_window_handle)
save = ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').perform()
save = ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: If I use just send_keys, the action is ok:

test = ActionChains(driver).send_keys('Test').perform()

Answer (score 0):

Why you use to "key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').perform()" ?

Did you try this:

```
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "s").perform()
```

Comment: When I use this, just type "s" on Google search bar, using Google.com as URL... The Ctrl doesn't work